# How to move the cursor of a QTextBrowser(with an html table in it) to a specific line in PyQt5?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I create a QTextBrowser to display an html table in my code. But when I tried to move the cursor to a specific line using the *setTextCursor* method, it failed to do that.

The scroll bar of the text browser indeed moved, but not to the specific line. Is this problem something to do with the html table?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QTextCursor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QTextBrowser, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QApplication

class MyTextBrowser(QTextBrowser):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MyTextBrowser, self).__init__(parent)
        self.createTable()

    def createTable(self, line_num = 1):
        # Create an html table with 100 lines
        html = '<table><tbody>'
        for i in range(0, 100):
            # Highlight specified line
            if line_num == i+1:
                html += '<tr style="background-color: #0000FF;"><td>Line</td><td>%d</td></tr>' % (i+1)
            else:
                html += '<tr><td>Line</td><td>%d</td></tr>' % (i+1)
        html += '</tbody></table>'
        self.setHtml(html)

        # Move the cursor to the specified line
        cursor = QTextCursor(self.document().findBlockByLineNumber(line_num))
        self.setTextCursor(cursor)

class MyWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.createLayout()

    def createLayout(self):
        # Create the text browser and a button
        self.textBrowser = MyTextBrowser()
        self.button = QPushButton('Move cursor')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)
        self.currentLine = 1

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.textBrowser)

        window = QWidget()
        window.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(window)

    def buttonClicked(self):
        # Move the cursor down for 10 lines when the button is clicked
        self.currentLine += 10
        if self.currentLine > 100:
            self.currentLine = 1

        self.textBrowser.createTable(self.currentLine)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MyWindow()
window.resize(640, 480)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trying, I discovered that QTextBrowser seems to treat each *td* tag as a new line.

So, instead of using

```
cursor = QTextCursor(self.document().findBlockByLineNumber(line_num))
self.setTextCursor(cursor)
```

We should use

```
cursor = QTextCursor(self.document().findBlockByLineNumber(line_num * td_num))
self.setTextCursor(cursor)
```

where *td_num* is the number of *td* tags in each row of the table.